# How to calculate the point on a projectile motion where magnitude of displacement is largest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, calculus

In a homework question assigned by my physics teacher, he claimed that the magnitude of displacement always increases throughout the projectile motion. That can’t be true since if you throw at 90 degrees, its magnitude of displacement decreases after the peak.

But anyways, is there a formula to find at what point in the projectile motion where the magnitude of displacement is the largest?

Answer (score 0):

Displacement is a change in position. Starting from $x(t)=x_0$ at $t=0$, then $\Delta x(t)= x(t) -x_0$. The maxima and minima of that function occur either in the ends of the independent variable interval or when the derivative (speed) is zero. So you solve for $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = 0$ and then compare with your boundary values.

If the movement is uniformly accelerated:

$$x(t) = x_0 + v_0 t + 0.5 a t^2$$
$$v(t) = \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = v_0 + a t$$

The time of zero speed is $t_0 = -v_0/a$. Now, compare the values $x(0)$, $x(t_m)$ and $x(t_{end})$ either in the formula for position or for displacement. The maximum of the three values is what you are searching for.

In 2D or 3D is similar but you solve for $\frac{dr(t)}{dt} = 0$, where $r(t) = |\vec{r}(t)| = \sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)+z^2(t)}$

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the projectile and the initial point is not increasing in general!

Suppose the projectile is located at $x=y=0$ and $t=0$. At $t>0$ we have
$$x(t)=v\cos \theta, \,\,\, y(t)=-\frac{1}{2}g t^2 + v\sin \theta \,t$$
The distance you are talking about is given by
$$L(t)=\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$$
To find the point at which this function becomes extremal, we solve for $\frac{d L}{dt}=0$. This gives the mathematical solution:
$$t_{1}=\frac{v}{2g}\big(3 \sin \theta -\sqrt{1- 9 \cos^2\theta}\big)$$
$$t_{2}=\frac{v}{2g}\big(3 \sin \theta +\sqrt{1- 9 \cos^2\theta}\big)$$

1. For $\theta < ArcCos(\frac{1}{3})$, $t_1$ and $t_2$ do not exist; this means that for these $\theta$ values, the distance $L$ is increasing during the projectile flight.
2. At $\theta = ArcCos(\frac{1}{3})$, function $L$ has a turning point.
3. For $\theta > ArcCos(\frac{1}{3})$, the maximum value of $L$ is $t_1$ and the minimum value is $t_2$. It turns out, however, that the minimum is a local minimum (see figures below). By solving $L(t_1)=L(\frac{2v sin \theta}{g})$, we numerically find that the maximum at $t=t_1$ is also a local maximum for $ArcCos(\frac{1}{3}<\theta\lesssim 1.28)$.
   ($1.27 \equiv 73.3 \text{ degrees}$) When $\theta>1.28$, maximum occurs at $t_1$.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In summary, for $\theta\lesssim 73.33 \text{ degrees}$, the distance $L$ is increasing; for $\theta\gtrsim 73.33 \text{ degrees}$ it has a maximum value. To find this $L_{max}$, you need to calculate $L(t_1)$, which is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to think about this in terms of vectors.  We can easily write down the expressions for $\mathbf{r}(t)$ and $\mathbf{v}(t)$, given what we know about projectile motion.  This means that the *square* of the displacement is $r^2 = \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r}$.  It can also be seen that at any point where the displacement is extremized, so is the square of the displacement;  in other words, we are looking for the point where
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} \right) = 0.
$$
But we also have by the product rule (which works for dot products just like it does for normal "algebraic" products
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{r} \right) = 2 \mathbf{r}\cdot\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} = 2 \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v}.
$$
This means, all told, that the displacement will be maximized when
$$
\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0,
$$
i.e., *the displacement is maximized at the $t$ for which the position and velocity vectors are perpendicular* (if such a $t$ exists.)

To actually find whether or not such a $t$ exists, you can then write out the quantity $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ in terms of $t$ and the initial conditions and find its roots.  In general, it will be a cubic polynomial in $t$;  and if the projectile starts at the origin, $t = 0$ will be one of the solutions.  Whether or not other solutions exist will depend on the relative values of the initial conditions.